# multiple Filters in Jasper Report

Tags: sql, swing, jasper-reports

I have Created a Student Information Report using Jasper report (SQL database). I need to filter the report using different parameters. e.g

Branch Wise
Gender Wise
Class Wise 
Section Wise and some more

I'm using Java Swing as a front end application.

My question is for each filter i have to write separate query?? or is there a way in jasper to manage different filter for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your query based on the parameter you got using a different expression which is $P!{}.

Follow below steps to achieve your needs,

> Create a parameter, say $P{BranchWise}.
>
> In the expression of that parameter, write something like

```
$P{Branch} != null ? "and branch = '"+$P{Branch}+"'" : ""
```

> Likewise create parameter for different filters.
>
> Now use these parameters in your query as below

```
select * from table1 where 1=1 $P!{BranchWise} $P!{GenderWise} $P!{ClassWise} ....
```

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you it solve my problem.. I was using "%" as a Default value before, but i think its taking much longer time to execute query. The one above you explain is good Approch

Comment: One thing though what do you mean by 1=1 ?

Comment: Condition 1=1 will be true for all case. If all the parameters are null, then only condition 1=1 will be executed. It is just used to avoid errors.

If this solution solves your problem kindly mark it as the answer which will be useful for others.